# move UIScrollView up when UITextField is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield

subview assigned to the UIScrollView. when the UITextField is selected UIScrollView should move up. I tried with below code but its not working.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    if( textField == citytextfield)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
        //set Y according to keyBoard height
        [_scrolling setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,-220.0,320.0,460.0)];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }



}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [_scrolling setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,320.0,460.0)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: What is `_scrolling`? Why are you not using block animations? Are you using auto layout? Are you sure you set yourself as the text field's delegate? Your title says you want to scroll the scroll view, but setting the frame doesn't make a scroll view scroll.

Comment: i set delegate for textfield.. okay i'll check it again replacing the view by scrollview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setContentOffset` method of `UIScrollView` to make it scroll up, yo will need to change the value `50` to your desired value.

```
[_scrolling setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,50) animated:YES];
```

Comment: i wrote this in textFieldDidBeginEditing but no change

Comment: @iOSDeveloper Check that you have set the textfield delegate and try with increasing the value 50 to something else.

Answer (score 0):

download the **tpkeyboardavoidingscrollview.**
give your scrollview's class name to tpkeyboardavoidingscrollview.

[image]

```
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView *scrollView;
```

set the property and give the connection to scrollview.
In your viewcontroller.h

```
#import "TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView"
```

then check it.